# Multiple Products Into one Simple Product

Tags: products, bundle

I would like to be able to create a bundle of products without the option to change quantity or list the items.

For example, if I am selling a knife set with multiple lengths 5", 4", 3" which can all be purchased separately, but I want to group them together and call it a set with 1 knife each without the option to choose a quantity.  Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To restrict the possibility of changing the quantity is quite straight forward. In your bundle product you have to set "user defined quantity" to "no" instead of "yes" and type in the backend the quantity for each product of the bundle.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I see that option but I think I might have stated the question wrong.   I am looking to make it a single product for example a "grouped" product without the option to change quantity.    Is there any way to do that with a grouped product?

Comment: From what I understand from your first question, you have the individual products already set up as simple products, is that correct? Do you need to have stock control of the items within the group? Depending on your answer to this second question, there are a few possible ways of doing it.

Comment: No, I do not need stock control on the simple products.

Comment: One route to go, although not the ideal one, would be adding those knives of the set as custom options.

Comment: Ok, that still gives them the option to choose.  I really need the ability to add all the products together and have it manage the price, etc.